# Not able to retrieve data from two table in Octobercms

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am new in OctoberCMS. I am facing problem retrieving data from two table. I have two tables Member and Profession.

```
Schema::create('members', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('member_name');            
            $table->text('member_detail');
            $table->string('member_city');
            $table->string('member_state');           
            $table->integer('profession_id')->nullable()->unsigned();           
        });
```

and

```
Schema::create('profession', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');          
        });
```

Member model related:

```
public $belongsTo = [
        'profession' => 'Harpal\Project\Models\Profession'                   
    ];
```

Profession model related:

```
public $hasOne = [
        'member' =>   'Harpal\Project\Models\Member'
    ];
```

In front-end, i want to retrieve data from both the tables using code

```
$members = Db::table('harpal_project_professions')
    ->join('harpal_project_members', 'harpal_project_professions.id', '=', 'harpal_project_members.profession_id')    
    ->select('harpal_project_professions.title', 'harpal_project_members.*')
   ->get();
    dd($this['members']);
```

It returns null in october cms. If i execute the above query in PHPmyAdmin it returns all the data. Can anyone help?

Comment: $members = Db::select('select m.*, p.title from harpal_project_members as m, harpal_project_professions as p where m.profession_id = p.id');  Tried this query  but the result is same null.

Comment: try to log the query and see what's query are you building

Comment: also please check the tables name, in the migration they are singular, but in the query they are plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the relation from one model or the other. These examples are used in a plugin's `component.php` file and it's `default.htm` file.

I want to retrieve members:

**PHP CODE**

```
use Author\Plugin\Models\Members;
public function getMembers() {
    return Members::all();
}
```

**TWIG CODE**

```
{% set members = __SELF__.getMembers() %}

{% for member in members %}
<p>{{ member.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Now I want to get the Profession Titles. In the twig code I can access it with dot (.) scheme (this won't work with `belongsToMany` or `hasMany`).

**TWIG CODE**

```
{% set members = __SELF__.getMembers() %}

{% for member in members %}
<p>{{ member.name }} - {{ member.profession.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Getting to the Profession data in PHP Code is just as easy. For example in a component I can filter members by profession:

```
use Author\Plugin\Models\Members;
public function getMembers() {
    return Members::all();
}

public function filterMembers($profession = null) {
    if ($profession) { //If profession query the model
        return Members::whereHas('profession', function ($query) use ($profession) { //Create query function using laravel whereHas method
            $query->where('title', $profession); // We want to return members with matching title
        })->get();
    } else {
        return Members::all(); // If no profession return all
    }
}
```

**TWIG CODE**

```
{% set members = __SELF__.filterMembers('Manager') %} //Notice that we are looking for profession title of 'Manager'

{% for member in members %}
<p>{{ member.name }} - Manager</p> 
{% endfor %} //We can hard code Manager because ware looking for only members that are manager
```

Comment if you need to clarify somehting.

Comment: Thanks Pettis Brandon <p>{{ member.name }} - {{ member.profession.title }}</p> This solved my problem. I am learning OctoberCMS. Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: @HarpalSingh Good deal. Glad I was able to help. Could you mark this as the answer please so we know this question is solved.